# How to express the content referenced by the anchor tag

Tags: html, semantics

I'd like to express in an HTML document what kind of document is pointed by an anchor tag (`<a>`). For example, is it a list of dates, or a list of people, etc... All referenced documents will be Atom feeds, but the links will be displayed differently based on what the feed contains.

I see 2 options :

1. **using the "rel" attribute :** this attribute is supposed to contains the *relation* between the current document and the referenced document. I don't think this is an optimal solution as this attribute is supposed to define the relation and not really the content. The referenced document will be a list of dates for all documents referencing it.
2. **using the "type" attribute :** this attribute is supposed to contains the content type of the referenced document. This solution seems closer to what I try to achieve, but this attribute should contains a content type and not a more generic description of the link.

Which solution would you recommend ? Do you see a cleaner way to achieve the same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class attribute, since your intent is make them appear different this would seem to be the best choice.

Comment: This is **SO** obvious that I didnt event think about it. It might be the right answer to my problem !

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like [microformats](http://microformats.org/) will help?

Answer (score 1):

`title` attribute on a link allows you to give the link a title which is displayed when it's hovered.

That might be what you want.

Comment: I think title AND rel would be advantageous

Comment: Actually, the HTML will be parsed and modified on the fly to include the content of the feed instead of the anchor. We really want something more precise than a title.